# how do I force the compilation of a widgetset in Vaadin?

Tags: eclipse, add-on, vaadin, sparklines

I am trying to use the sparklines add on in my application. However, eclipse systematically refuses to compile the corresponding widgetset, i.e. if I specify the `inherit` tag in my widgetset that refers to the sparklines widgetset as follows:

```
<inherits name="org.vaadin.artur.icepush.IcepushaddonWidgetset" />
<inherits name="org.vaadin.hezamu.googlemapwidget.widgetset.GooglemapwidgetWidgetset" />
<inherits name="org.vaadin.sparklines.SparklinesWidgetset" />
<inherits name="com.fluxtream.widgets.FluxtreamwidgetsWidgetset" />
```

...eclipse complains with the following error:

```
Loading inherited module 'com.fluxtream.widgets.FluxtreamwidgetsWidgetset'
   Loading inherited module 'com.fluxtream.dashboard.widgetset.FlxDashboardWidgetset'
      Loading inherited module 'org.vaadin.sparklines.SparklinesWidgetset'
         [ERROR] Unable to find 'org/vaadin/sparklines/SparklinesWidgetset.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
      [ERROR] Line 26: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
```

However, I have verified that the widgetset was indeed declared as a dependency in my project's pom, and I have also verified that it appears under the "Maven Dependencies" library icon in the eclipse IDE.

Also, whenever I attempt to recompile my widgetset, and after the aforementioned error is displayed, I can see that my original widgetset.gwt.xml file has been modified, and as a result would look as follows:

```
<inherits name="org.vaadin.artur.icepush.IcepushaddonWidgetset" />
<inherits name="org.vaadin.hezamu.googlemapwidget.widgetset.GooglemapwidgetWidgetset" />

<inherits name="com.fluxtream.widgets.FluxtreamwidgetsWidgetset" />


<inherits name="com.fluxtream.dashboard.widgetset.FlxDashboardWidgetset" />
```

I'm really confused, as I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I am using other add-ons which work just fine (icepush and googlemap) and I really don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Vaadin Eclipse plugin manages your gwt.xml, that is why it is modifies if you add/remove add-on from classpath.
Basically this means that you don't have to modify the gwt.xml by hand, if working in Eclipse. Furthermore, the Eclipse plugin does not know anything about maven (or pom files) and any information in those does not affect to it.

You can compile the widgetset two ways. First with the Eclipse plugin (the button on toolbar) or with maven. This sounds that you are mixing those.

Easiest setup is to put all add-on jars to WEB-INF/lib and use the eclipse plugin to compile the widgetset. The gwt.xml should be automatically updated, but sometimes a refresh (or jar remove/add procedure) is needed to let the plugin notice change.

Also, check the Vaadin settings in project preferences are the way you want.

Comment: I had forgotten that I had to put the add-on jars in WEB-INF/lib. Thanks. It's a bit confusing that you have both to put it in the pom as a dependency AND copy the jars to WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Yes, the installation of Vaadin add-ons is a real pain point for me too